# Assign integer value to letter

Tags: c#

So i have this problem. I have Text Box with text containing 12 numbers. So for example 012345678912. Now i don't know how to assign the first, then the second .... and so on numbers to letters like a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l because i need them to calculate the 13th (m) number with the following formula

```
m = 11 − (( 7*(a+g) + 6*(b+h) + 5*(c+i) + 4*(d+j) + 3*(e+k) + 2*(f+l) ) mod 11)
```

Also i tried to make this formula in to c# readable text and i got this, hope it is correct

```
int result = (int)new DataTable().Compute(" 11 − (( 7*(a+g) + 6*(b+h) + 5*(c+i) + 4*(d+j) + 3*(e+k) + 2*(f+l) ) mod 11)", null);
```

Comment: Do not call digits or numeric characters 'numbers' ! Also note that a string can be read as a character array! Finally: Do not call variables 'letters'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are plenty of approaches that you can adapt to achieve this. But if you really want to declare the variables as a,b,c,d,etc.

you can simply declare all these letters first. Once you have done that you can use for each loop as follows

**Code**

```
            int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l;

// conversion of whole value in text box to single integers
            char[] digits_array = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray(); 

//Now just declare each variable as you want there are several ways to do it    
            a = int.Parse(digits_array[0].ToString());
            b = int.Parse(digits_array[1].ToString());
            c = int.Parse(digits_array[2].ToString());
            d = int.Parse(digits_array[3].ToString());
            e = int.Parse(digits_array[4].ToString());
            f = int.Parse(digits_array[5].ToString());
            g = int.Parse(digits_array[6].ToString());
            h = int.Parse(digits_array[7].ToString());
            i = int.Parse(digits_array[8].ToString());
            j = int.Parse(digits_array[9].ToString());
            k = int.Parse(digits_array[10].ToString());
            l = int.Parse(digits_array[11].ToString());
```

Now You can simply use these values in your Formaula the main function that i used here is **.ToCharArray() Function** . I have checked the script and its working fine Hoever the script seems pretty Long So I want other developers to help me out to squeeze this code. I tried Plenty of things apart from this method but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = int.Parse(txtNumbers.Text);

int a[12];
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    a[i] = x %12;
    x = x/10;
}
```

Comment: I hope you are ok with using array rather than variables a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k.

Comment: Why `x % 12`? Also, a 12 digit number will overlow the `int` range.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit broad.  There's quite a lot of ways to do what you're suggesting.

One way would simply be to assign a - l to values, as variables, such as:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
...
```

Another way would be with an Dictionary

```
Dictionary<char, int> Alpha = new Dictionary<char,int>() 
{ 
   {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3} ...
};
```

You could use an enumeration

```
public enum Alphabet
{
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3,
  ...
}

Alphabet alpha = Alphabet.B;
Console.WriteLine((int)alpha);
```

Etc.